# Save Popup Configurations in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, popup, configuration, save

Is there a way to save configured pop-ups within ArcGIS Online and then use the saved configuration in other ArcGIS Online web maps?

Comment: What kind of layer are you asking about? ArcGIS Server hosted or ArcGIS Online hosted?

Comment: Either Server hosted or ArcGIS online hosted, I use both.

Answer (score 3):

*M answer applies to ArcGIS Layers. For ArcGIS Server layers, see whyzar's answer, and the last part of this answer.*

In ArcGIS Online:

1. go to the Content tab and find the layer you are interested in setting popups for
2. Click the layer to get to its settings (not shown in picture)
3. Click the Visualization tab
4. Click the Configure Popups button
5. When done setting up the popup, click either Save Layer or Save As New Layer

Now when you add this layer to any map, these settings will be set already.

This works for Map Image Layers, Feature Layers, Imagery Layers, Stream Layers, thanks to Russ Roberts for adding this info. I tested this with a map image layer that references an ArcGIS Server service, and it worked when the reference was to a single layer, but not group layers.

[image: Location of buttons referenced in answer]

Comment: You can save the popup configuration for other layer items as well not just hosted feature layers. You can save the popup configuration back to the item through the visualization tab or the map viewer.

Comment: @RussRoberts Thanks for the comment. Do you know what layer types this works for? I could not find this listed in the documentation.

Comment: Yup you can do this for these item types Map Image Layers, Feature Layers, Imagery Layers, Stream Layers. You can also do this for tile layers that have a popup being driven from a dynamic layer in the map viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Esri's [Configure pop-ups](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm)

> Pop-up configurations you make on layers you own can be saved with the item properties and automatically enabled on other maps using that layer. The configuration applies to the layer in the map only and not the actual service running on your ArcGIS Server.

I'm not sure of an alternative that may be available either at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done in the past - open the map image layer or otherwise in a map viewer. Configure the pop-ups as needed and then, going back to the properties for the layer, select 'Save Layer'.